# Chrome (MAC OSX) not releasing img from memory

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I noticed that Chrome keeps using more and more memory when simply browsing through my website (unfortunately not live at the moment).

**I narrowed it down to:**

Images are not being released from the memory. Create a simple html page with some random images and refresh the page. Notice the (quite large) increase in memory every time new images are being loaded.

**Example:**

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=1" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=2" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=3" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=4" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=5" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=6" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=7" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=8" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=9" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500?rand=10" />
```

Or view this http://jsfiddle.net/46r9amz0/1/embedded/result/

Chrome is using 100mb on the first pageload, after refreshing the page 15 times it's reporting 600mb.

Tested on Chrome 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit), using OSX 10.9.5. I cannot reproduce this issue on e.g. Firefox.

**Edit:** Tested the issue on Windows 7 using Chrome, the page stays at around 30mb memory, so it seems the issue is only present on MAC OSX

**Question:** How do i prevent or fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I cant replicate your issue but have you tried preventing cache ! also which OS is this on? I know from previous experience chrome on mac has some glitches

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just tested the original example on a Windows 7 machine using the latest Chrome. Memory usage here stays the same (hovering around 30mb). Looks like the issue is only present on MAC OSX. Disabling cache is not making a difference.